# X99 2011-v3 Motherboard and 128 GB DDR4 RAM Compatibility

Tags: motherboard, memory

I have a question about a motherboard and RAM compatibility.

[MSI X99A XPOWER AC LGA 2011-v3 Intel X99 SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.1 USB 3.0 Extended ATX Intel Motherboard](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813130836)

and

[CORSAIR Dominator Platinum 128GB (8 x 16GB) 288-Pin DDR4 SDRAM DDR4 2800 (PC4 22400) Desktop Memory Model CMD128GX4M8B2800C14](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820233814)

I couldn't find this RAM in the supported list on MSI's website. I have a feeling that the page is not updated as it doesn't even list any 16 GB modules. Similarly, Corsair's website lists only two motherboards as supported, ASUS X99 Deluxe and Rampage V Extreme. pcpartpicker.com does not list this RAM when this board and Intel i7-5960 Haswell-E are selected.

I wanted to double check before investing almost $1,700 on these two components.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to [Intel ARK on the Intel® Core™ i7-5930K Processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/82931/Intel-Core-i7-5930K-Processor-15M-Cache-up-to-3_70-GHz):

- Max Memory Size (dependent on memory type): 64 GB
- Memory Types: DDR4 1333/1600/2133
- Max # of Memory Channels: 4
- Max Memory Bandwidth: 68GB/s
- ECC Memory Supported: No

So, I won't be able to use 128 GB.

Comment: Did you select your own answer repeating the already posted and correct answer by @Peter Zhu?

Answer (score 6):

You will not be able to use that set of RAM since the CPU doesn't support. Even though the motherboard supports 128GB of RAM, the CPU unfortunately only supports up to 64GB of RAM. The only way to max out your RAM right now is to get 8 x 8GB sticks. To support the full 128GB of RAM, you would need a Xeon CPU that works in the LGA 2011 socket.